# Config apache and nodejs socket.io

Tags: node.js, apache, sockets, socket.io, feathersjs

Hi I'm working on a website using apache 2.2 and feathersjs.
on this website we have DV SSL so we can't access subdomains using https.

my node application is running on 3030 port. so I can access to feathersjs app using this address:

http://mywebsite.com:3030

but https://mywebsite.com:3030 not working.

I need to use a Location like https://mywebsite.com/socket/ to connect to feathersjs websocket (guess ws://localhost:3030)

here is client side code:

```
const host = 'https://mywebsite.com/socket';
const socket = io(host,{
            transports: ['websocket'],
            forceNew: true
        });
```

**I need httpd configuration to connect ws over https.**

post_virtualhost_global.conf

```
<VirtualHost 185.173.106.42:80>
  ServerName mywebsite.com

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} Upgrade$ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* ws://localhost:3030%{REQUEST_URI} [P]

    ProxyPass /socket http://localhost:3030/
    ProxyPassReverse /socket http://localhost:3030/

    ProxyRequests off

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 185.173.106.42:443>
  ServerName freevery.com

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} Upgrade$ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* ws://localhost:3030%{REQUEST_URI} [P]

    ProxyPass /socket http://localhost:3030/
    ProxyPassReverse /socket http://localhost:3030/

    ProxyRequests off

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location /feathers>
        ProxyPass http://localhost:3030/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3030/
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

if I try to connect web socket using http://mywebsite.com/socket it says

> Failed to load
>   http://mywebsite.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=L-1lgZ1:
>   Redirect from
>   'http://mywebsite.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=L-1lgZ1' to
>   'https://mywebsie.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=L-1lgZ1'
>   has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource. Origin
>   'http://localhost:3001' is therefore not allowed access.

and if I try to connect web socket using https://mywebsite.com/socket it says

> Failed to load
>   https://mywebsite.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=L-1lUP5: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3001' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

I added `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` to my .htaccess file but problem exists.

**what is wrong with my configurations?**

Comment: Try adding `ProxyPreserveHost On`

Comment: now I have `websocket.js:112 WebSocket connection to 'ws://mywebsite.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 301`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Apache had conflicts with nginx and 301 error was form it. So I used nginx to proxy websocket and it's working on a subdomain without any problem.